# Node express parent folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using node and express as a simple html server for my website. Since today my server.js was in the same folder as my index.hmtl so this code was all i needed:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname)); 
app.listen(80);
console.log('Listening on port 80');
```

Today i moved the server.js into a second folder named server and the index.html is placed in the parent folder. I have no idea how to change my script so that it works again and i didn't found anything in the www.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you realize that `app.use(express.static(__dirname))` is what you use to tell express where to find your static content? Like your index.html page.

So all you need to do is to tell express that you content is now in the parent folder of the the current directory of your server.js module:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'..'));
```

Comment: Ok that was dumb sry. yeah.. no idea why i did not try this solution. Thank you.